# Prefer binary package in setup.cfg

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging, greenlets

My project (https://github.com/locustio/locust) depends on `greenlet`, but whenever there is a new release of that, there is a brief period when no binary version is available, and many of my users have issues with installing from source.

Is there a way to prefer an older binary version instead of the latest and greatest source version? E.g. prefer 2.0.1 that has a binary version over 2.0.2 that doesn't (or at least didn't at the time)

Considered alternate solutions:

- Set `--prefer-binary` from the pip command line, but it is somewhat hard to explain that to people.
- I could just lock it to 2.0.1, but that is overly rigid.

Comment: Not possible. It is up to your users to handle this, the ones doing the installation, not your responsibility.

Comment: That's too bad! I understand that it is not really in setuptools's concern/scope but it is kind of hard to educate our thousands of users, especially the ones unfamiliar to Python/pip. Perhaps I should document "pip install --prefer-binary locust" as the suggested installation method, but that also feels weird :)

Comment: Documenting is the best, in my opinion -- I guess there are other things you could do to minimize the issue reports coming your way, but that would probably mean much more work on your side. -- One (silly) measure I can think of, off the top of my head, is to publish post-build releases: one post-build to exclude the new version of greenlet that is sdist-only, then followed by another post-build to allow again that version of greenlet once it has wheels. -- You could maybe ask there for ideas (or at least raise awareness): https://discuss.python.org/c/packaging/14

Comment: A better course of action, would be obviously to get greenlet to always distribute wheels immediately, whether with some "lobbying" or with actual help getting their CI/CD to build wheels automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I’ll ping the greenlet guys to start with!